# Size filter is not working

Tags: magento-1.7

I have added **size** filter in Manadev Layered Navigation

```
Catalog Input Type for Store  - Multiple Select
```

Size filter is based on Range i.e

```
1.  0 to 0.5  
2.  0.5 to 1  
3.  1 to 1.5
```

Filter works fine when I update the record in `catalog_product_index_eav,  catalog_product_index_eav_tmp and catalog_product_entity_varchar` table.
But when I come next day , filter value get changed on above table.

Can anyone tell the reason why it is happening?

Is this because I have not updated the same in catalog_product_index_eav_idx  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have stopped product attribute indexing.